# How do I download/extract font from chrome developers tools?

Tags: fonts, google-chrome-devtools

I have tired many things but i can't get it even though my computer has it.

How can I access this wont files? They have the .woff extension. Double clicking them in chrome  inspector just takes to some url. Which doesn't work.

Nor this font is installed on my computer.

This is in fact first time in my life I have come across woff format and the concept web open format. I want to download the font website is using. I know I can download the images why not wont.

[image]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Right-click, then "Open link in new tab"

**edit :** you can also double-click, it has the same effect

Comment: Indeed, in your particular example it seems the server returns a `403 - Forbidden` response to the request initiated by the action. Anyway, I was able to save the fonts by exploring chrome cache at `chrome://cache`. Search "woff" then "Right-click / Save link as..."

Comment: i am able to get woff file now but it seems it's not working and it gives error if converted to ttf/oft type too.

Comment: I realized that the saved file contains also the meta-informations useful to Chrome. So as to get only the payload you can try the freeware ChromeCacheView.

Comment: is there a way in this program to save file and not just save its information as that's whats happening. Also normally woff fonts type appear as 'font/woff' whereas the one i want has its type appears as 'application/x-font-woff'

Comment: Go in the `File` menu, then `Copy selected cache files to... (F4)`. The action `Save selected Items` is indeed confusing as it saves only the information about the items.

Comment: ok the font works now and i can save it. However i am not able to convert it to ttf or otf but that's a different problem thanks for all the help really...i had no idea there was chrome cache tool and it was available at chrome://cache thanks...

Comment: When it says forbidden/403 response, most probably they are checking referer. Do this -> Inspect any anchor link on the same page where the font is, change its href to font link and click that link, it will download the font file.

Comment: where on the PC do the files actually download to? any idea?

Answer (score 79):

To get *.woff* fonts first open the chrome dev tools panel (`Ctrl+Shift+i`) go to **Network** and reload the page. There you will see everything the page downloads. Find the .woff file, **right click** and select **Copy response**.

The response will be a url so **paste it in the navigation bar**. A file will be downloaded, just **add the *.woff* extension** to it and voila.

Comment: This is such a time saver, thanks so much for posting. Never used the Network tab before, fantastic!

Comment: instead of "copy response" just double click it - it will download the file

Comment: Very Helpful specially when work with big client, they want to use paid font but take too much time for providing the genuine font file, this is really time saver!

Comment: This is the correct answer, because some font urls won't open "in the tab" (like 403 Error).

Comment: I had to click "Copy link address", not "Copy response", but it did work.

Answer (score 12):

## The best way so far

is to actaully go to `rightclick: inspect > Application (on the top tabs) > Frames (scroll on the left tabs)` Then you can find a `Font` section where all loaded fonts are listed. It lists all that are loaded in any possible secure way.

Further more, It also previews them on the right, to make it even easier

[image: Application tab]

Then you can right-click on the one you want and open in a new tab. Then you can add a .woff at the end and use it anywhere. (you can check its extension on the bottom of the preview too)

Comment: In addition, if you cannot see the font extension, you could use TriD to tell you what file type it is. Download link: https://mark0.net/software-e.html

Answer (score 11):

It's easy (For Chorme only)

1. Right click > inspect element
2. Go to 'Resources' tab  and find 'Fonts' in dropdown folders

   - *'Resouces' tab may be called 'Application'*
3. Right click on font (in `.woff` format) > open link in new tab (this should download the font in `.woff` format
4. Find a 'Woff to TTf or Otf' font converter online
5. Enjoy after conversion!

Answer (score 8):

Open chrome

Right click => inspect => navigate to **application** tab

In **Frames** section, all the statically available assets(resources) such as css, JavaScript, fonts are listed.

Comment: this is the best solution and always reliable solution, including those that don't have a direct woff file download

Answer (score 3):

If you are on a unixoid operating system and want to extract just a single file you can try the following. The structure of the `chrome://cache` pages is URL, parsed HTTP header, hex dump of the HTTP header and then hex dump of the payload.

To extract a file copy all payload lines from a Chrome cache page to the clipboard (starting at the second `00000000: ...` line), paste them into a text editor and save them as a plain text file (e.g. `file.txt`). If the payload is a gzipped WOFF file use `xxd -r file.txt > file.woff.gz` to convert it back to a binary file and `gunzip file.woff.gz` for decompression.

You can then use [woff2otf](https://github.com/hanikesn/woff2otf) to convert WOFF files to the OTF format or [woff2](https://github.com/google/woff2) to convert WOFF 2.0 files to the TTF format. For batch processing this workflow should obviously be scripted.

Answer (score 2):

I found the Chrome option to be OK but there are quite a few steps to go through to get to the font files. Once you're there, the downloading is super easy. I usually use the dev tools in Safari as there are fewer steps. Just go to the page you want, click on "Show page source" or "show page resources" in the Developer menu (both work for this) and the page resources are listed in folders on the left hand side. Click the font folder and the fonts are listed. Right click and save file. If you are downloading a lot of font files from one site it may be quicker to work your way through Chrome's pathway as the "open in tab" does download the fonts quicker. If you're taking one or two fonts from a lot of different sites, Safari will be quicker overall.

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me

Answer (score -2):

Although Marcelo's solution seems to be working great, you may not need to download the font at all! **Just link to it remotely**.

E.g the font is hosted on *example.com*, do

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Font Name";
  font-style: normal;
  src: url(http://example.com/webfonts/font-name.woff);
}
```

You may easily figure out the direct url to the font by looking into css code from *example.com* and see how they linked the file.