# How do i download/extract font from firefox developers tools

Tags: fonts, firefox-developer-tools

I have read the similar post for Chrome ([how do i download/extract font from chrome developers tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711393/how-do-i-download-extract-font-from-chrome-developers-tools)) and I'm trying to do the same thing using Firefox instead. So I have opened the network panel fo dev tools and reloaded the page, then filtered for the actual `GET 200` answer and I see `content-encoding: gzip` and `content-lenght: 238214` all good.

Now if I open the answer panel instead the header i can copy/paste the answer as text stream but this is not even close to the above specified size. I tried to convert to gzip as specified using an online tool but the result was in any case a corrupted .gz file instead. Why it is not working with firefox? What am I doing wrong?

**edit**: the test URL that I used is: https://fonts.adobe.com/fonts/exocet

Answer (score 9):

To download the webfont you can simply right-click the request and choose *Open in New Tab* from the context menu.

[image: Open web font in new tab]

This will open the download dialog:

[image: Download dialog]

Note that you may need to reload the page without caching, i.e. by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or disabling the cache via the *Disable Cache* option in the Network panel, in order to see the requests for the font files. This is because Firefox has a special font cache and it doesn't make any requests to the font files once they are cached.

*Please note that using web fonts may be restricted by copyrights.*

Comment: this didnt work for me, the downloaded font was a placeholder, it looks like that the real font is replaced dynamically. Any possible solution to this?

Comment: One or two screenshots of the request and what you're doing would help, I guess. Note that you may need to reload the page without cache, i.e. by pressing Ctrl+F5 to actually see the font request. Important question is, does it work in the Chrome DevTools? If so, it's something related to Firefox. If not, it is a general issue related to the website or how you try to download the font.

Comment: I've edited my answer explaining that the font files are only shown when reloading without caching.

Comment: Tried in Chrome too just to make sure was not related to Firefox, I opened the network panel and reloaded the page to "listen" and filtered for Fonts, but when donwloaded I had a blank font full of rectangles with X inside while on the screen I were able to preview the actual font.

Comment: It's hard to reproduce what you are seeing without more information. Please edit your question and add screenshots, the precise steps of what you did, and if possible the URL of the website you are referring to.

Comment: Added the sample URL but I replicated the same behavior on other URLs of the same website. It seems that it is rewriting the font dynamically.